# Fresnel integral: stationary phase approx.

Tags: integration, physics, approximate-integration, fresnel-integrals

The following integral describes the propagation of light (in certain cases)
$$
U_i(x,y,z) = 
\frac{e^{ikz}}{i\lambda z}
 \int_{-\infty}^\infty d\xi \int_{-\infty}^\infty d\eta  \;
U_0(\xi, \eta,0) \,
\exp\left({i \frac{k}{2z}\left[
(x-\xi)^2 + (y-\eta)^2
\right]
}\right)
$$
In the limit $z\to 0$ it is said that the quadratic phase factor act like a Dirac $\delta$ distribution. While this is intuitively clear (in the context of optics) I don't see how it works mathematically.

- $k=2\pi/\lambda > 0$ is the wave number,
- $\lambda>0$ is the wavelength,
- $(x,y,z)$ is a position, and so is $(\xi, \eta, 0)$. Hence, they are all real numbers.
- $U_0$ is a real valued function, which represent the electric field. It is a "well-behaved" function (i.e. finite, and smooth). Usually we consider that it differs from zero only on a finite surface $\Sigma$ -- the aperture.

Comment: Can you be more specific about $U_0$ and the domain of integration? Is $U_0$ a compactly supported smooth function or a Schwartz functoin? Are $k$ and $z$ real and positive?

Answer (score 1):

1. We can write $U_i$ as a convolution between two function, $U_0$ and $h(x,y,z) = \ldots$
   $$
   U_i(x,y,z) = U_0(x,y,0) * h(x,y,z)
   $$
2. Next, we Fourier transform both sides (in 2D)  and use the Fourier theorem for convolutions. This yields
   $$
   \tilde U_i(f_x, f_y, z) = \tilde U_0(f_x,f_y, 0) \cdot \tilde h(f_x,f_y,z)
   $$
   Doing the calculation, we get
   $
   \tilde h(f_x,f_y,z) = e^{ikz} e^{-i\pi \lambda z (f_x^2 + f_y^2)}
   $.
3. Now, we take the limit  $z\to 0$ and obtain $\tilde h(f_x,f_y,0) = 1$.
4. Finally, we use the inverse 2D Fourier transform on both sides as well as the Fourier theorem for convolutions. This yields
   $$
   U_i(x,y,z) = U_0(x,y) * \mathcal{F}^{-1}\{1\}
   = U_0(x,y) * \delta(x,y)
   $$